# ARM template deployment for Logic Apps with Datalake API Connection

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

Error - The API connection 'azuredatalake' is not configured to support managed identity."

I tried deployment of Azure logic App along with API connection to access Azure DataLake Gen1 using Managed Identity. This failed due to above error.

Also deployed API connection separately which was successful but with status "Unauthenticated", so deploying of corresponding logic apps failed with missing api connection.

Part Template for API connection reference:

```
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('azuredatalake_1_Connection_Name')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "kind": "V1",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "azuredatalakemsi",
                "customParameterValues": {},
                "api": {
                    "id": "[variables('managedadlsApi')]"
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to access the data stored in data lake gen1, we must configure right ACLs for the user or sp used to do auth. Otherwise, we cannot have permission to access data. For more details, please refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-security-overview#using-acls-for-operations-on-file-systems). Meanwhile, we cannot do that via arm template. We can do that by PowerShell or Portal.

Besides, regarding how to use MSI to access Azure data lake gen1 in azure logic app, please refer to the following steps

1. Enable MSI in Azure logic app

```
{
   "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
   "type": "Microsoft.logic/workflows",
   "name": "[variables('logicappName')]",
   "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
   "identity": {
      "type": "SystemAssigned"
   },
   "properties": {
      "definition": {
         "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
         "actions": {},
         "parameters": {},
         "triggers": {},
         "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
         "outputs": {}
   },
   "parameters": {},
   "dependsOn": []
}
```

2. [Configure ACLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-secure-data)
3. Create connection

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('azuredatalake_1_Connection_Name')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": {
                "CreatedTime": "2021-05-24T03:11:28.9371899Z"
            },
            "kind": "V1",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "test",
                "customParameterValues": {},
                "api": {
                    "id": "[concat(subscription().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('location'), '/managedApis/azuredatalake')]"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
            "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
            "name": "[parameters('workflows_testlogic05_name')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('azuredatalake_1_Connection_Name'))]"
            ],
            
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled",
                "definition": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {
                        "$connections": {
                            "defaultValue": {},
                            "type": "Object"
                        }
                    },
                    "triggers": {
                        
                    },
                    "actions": {
                        
                    },
                    "outputs": {}
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "$connections": {
                        "value": {
                            "azuredatalake": {
                                "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('azuredatalake_1_Connection_Name'))]",
                                "connectionName": "azuredatalake",
                                "connectionProperties": {
                                    "authentication": {
                                        "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
                                    }
                                },
                                "id": "[concat(subscription().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('location'), '/managedApis/azuredatalake')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

For more details, please refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity

Comment: I was able to create azuredatalake api connection(MSI) directly inside logic apps, so this shouldn't be an issue with ACL. I have found solution which is working, will post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by modifying ARM Template for this API connection, that is by adding "parameterValueType" as "Alternative".

Deployment of Azure logic App along with API connection to access Azure DataLake Gen1 using Managed Identity is successful.

Part Template for API connection reference:

```
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('azuredatalake_1_Connection_Name')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "kind": "V1",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "azuredatalakemsi",
                "parameterValueType": "Alternative",
                "customParameterValues": {},
                "api": {
                    "id": "[variables('managedadlsApi')]"
                }
            }
        }
```